# No Sound after installing windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio, sigmatel

I installed win7 on my laptop and everything works except the sound. The sound card is a SigmaTel 9750. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try download and install this driver:

http://www.dell.com/support/troubleshooting/us/en/19/KCS/KcsArticles/ArticleView?docid=DSN_CE11FD8615163B4CE030A68F272840C0

I've had problems in the past with sound going funny after an OS installl